# how can I get jtable to show multiple lines in a row

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe, jtable

and i would like my data to show like this:
[MySql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75hfr.png)
but i only get this:
[java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGN4i.png)

I used this query:
`GROUP_CONCAT(a.montant, a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark SEPARATOR '\n') as Avance`

and it works just fine in MySql but it doesn't work in jframe.

this my java code:

```
//declaring the table
tb_imp_pr = new JTable();
        tb_imp_pr.setRowHeight(50);
        tb_imp_pr.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tb_imp_pr);
```

```
// filling the table
public void filltable_pr() {
        try {
            connectore.statement = connectore.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT i.*,GROUP_CONCAT(a.montant,"
+" a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark SEPARATOR '\n') as Avance "
+" FROM info_impayee i LEFT JOIN avance a ON i.n_dossier = a.n_dossier GROUP by i.n_dossier,i.date_dossier");
            connectore.resultSet = connectore.statement.executeQuery();
            tb_imp_pr.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(connectore.resultSet));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println();
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: [and it works just fine in MySql but it doesn't work in jframe.](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/77-doesntwork)

Comment: The default renderer for a JTable is a JLabel. A JLabel will not display multiple lines when using "\n". You can use HTML with the <br> tag to display multiple lines. However, you will also need to set the row height in the table.

Comment: @camickr  , I did try <html><br></html> but it didn't work too, I might have done wrong

Comment: You actually need to add text before and after the <br>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @camickr
i know that i need to use "br" and have text before and after the "br"

```
public void filltable_pr() {
try {
connectore.statement = connectore.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT i.*,GROUP_CONCAT('<html>',a.montant,"
+" a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark SEPARATOR '<br></html>') as Avance "
+" FROM info_impayee i LEFT JOIN avance a ON i.n_dossier = a.n_dossier GROUP by i.n_dossier,i.date_dossier");
connectore.resultSet = connectore.statement.executeQuery();
tb_imp_pr.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(connectore.resultSet));
} catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
   }     
}
```

Comment: repeating: java naming conventions please